# I'm using Java ADT and I imported a project and I got: Unable to resolve target 'android-18' until the SDK is loaded

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I'm making a Bird Song quiz game with sound and pictures. I'm using Java ADT and I imported the project, then I had to download a new ADT. Now I'm getting: Unable to resolve target 'android-18' until the SDK is loaded.

I'm also getting this, which seems to be a smaller problem (I've been able to fix it before): The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project

What should I do?

Comment: So I suppose you updated your ADT right to fix the first issue?
The second part: open the properties for the project and look under `Java Build Path` is there any "red crosses" in the `Libraries` tab?

Comment: No, there aren't. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project that you have imported.
Go to Properties -> Android -> Project Build Target

[image]

Just like mine , none of the checkboxes will be checked in your's too.
Click/ Tick on any check box.

[image]

Then Press Apply-> OK

Your issue of "Unable to resolve target" will get solved.
Hope this hepls. Comment for further help.